# How can I access GitLab CI CD Environment variables in .net core 2.2 webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, gitlab, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment

I have some connection strings and confidential data in config which I want to move out of the code for security reasons and move it to Environment variables in Gitlab. But don't know how to use and implement that.
any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You just have to replace the hard coded value with :  Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Name")

Comment: Have a look at [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#environment-variables-configuration-provider) ...

Comment: @jdweng  How the application will access the GitLab CICD Environment variable.

Comment: using in c# : string cicd = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Name")

Comment: @jdweng this "Name" variable is store in GITLAB CICD pipeline as Environment Variable with prefix k8s_secret_ . Dircet access is giving null. Hope there should be  a way to load Gitlab CICD env variables in Hostbuilder

Comment: You need to look at the GitHub source code.

Comment: @jdweng ok I'll check in that. Thanks for your time and help :)

Comment: @AmitSingh ,  I'm also getting null when trying to access this variable using  Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Name") , Did you find out how to access it ?!

Answer (score 0):

After creating a variable in GitLab CI/CD under Settings -> CI/CD -> Variables, I am able to read the value in C# using this:

```
string gitLabVar = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("VARNAME", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
```